# asp.net merge more language in one culture

Tags: asp.net, culture

i'm using asp.net integrated language system for making my site multi-language.

I used `Culture="auto:it-IT" UICulture="auto"` in every page to get italian as main language. Now i want my site to display in english too.
I created another resource file with all the english translations and named it **mypage.aspx.en-US.resx**.

When visiting my page from USA my site take the correct translation, but if i access it from uk, canada or any other place who speaks english it takes the default language.
i don't want to create one new .resx file for every language (only for english there are 17 variants) and don't want to use en-US as default language because my site must have a lot of language so i'll eventually have the same problem with some other language.

How i can get all the en-US en-GB en-CA (and 14 more en-XX) to get a standard "en" language wrote in a single resource file?

Answer (score 0):

solution found!
just create a resource file named mypage.aspx.en.resx to cover all the english variants :D